# I would go out with him but he didn't ask me

Tags: sentence-structure

> I would go out with him but he didn't ask me.
>
> I would have gone out with him but he didn't ask me.

I think the second one is correct. But what about the first one?

Comment: Your're right. The first one is awkward: More natural would be: **I would go out with him but he doesn't ask me**

Comment: @RonaldSole  That sounds equally odd, although mostly because it's not logical.  I would rather say, *"I would go out with him but he **hasn't asked** me (yet)"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two sentences are both grammatical, but have slightly different meanings.

I would punctuate the first one with a dash, to show that the second clause is more of a clarification or afterthought, as the time-frame is different in each of the two clauses.

> I would go out with him — but he didn't ask me.

Had he asked you, you might have a date for the upcoming weekend, for example. The first clause is present-and-forward-looking; the second makes a statement about the past.

With the second sentence you're explaining why it was that the two of you did not go out together or aren't going out together or are not intending to go out together.

> I would have gone out with him but he didn't ask me.

The second part in the simple past is again confined to the past (he didn't ask) but the first part with **would** could be understood as "modal remoteness" — as statement of something that *could have happened* if things had been different.

The first implies that you would indeed still go out with him if he were to ask.

The second is silent in that regard.  You might hold a grudge or might not. You might say yes or you might say no, were he to ask you now.

> I would have gone out with him, but he didn't ask me to the prom.  He had his chance and bungled it.
>
> I would have gone out with him, but he didn't ask.  Maybe he had some other obligation. I suppose if he asked me now, I'd say yes.

Answer (score 0):

this expression could you say too this way:

> I would like go out with him but he doesn't ask me

but the second sound more natural like american speaker english so you have a little mistake in the part didn't you should use  **does not** and not **did not** because when you say **did not** in the past thing and you  want to say in the present  why are you waiting him asks